# How to "fix" Amazon Developer Account?

Tags: amazon-s3

I've tried asking on Amazon forums, but [no one seems willing to help there](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=510287)...

I signed up for the free developer account a while ago but I never used it. Last night, I signed up for Amazon's S3 service.

When I attempt to use [Amazon's command line tools](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) to access S3, I get an error:

```
$ aws s3 ls
A client error (NotSignedUp) occurred when calling the ListBuckets
operation: Your account is not signed up for the S3 service. You must
sign up before you can use S3.
```

When I visit Amazon's portal at https://portal.aws.amazon.com, I'm told I already have it. I believe this is correct since I previously signed up for it.

[image]

When I attempt to contact support, I'm told to purchase a support incident!

[image]

I refuse to purchase a support incident while trying out the service, and I'm absolutely befuddled Amazon wants money from me for a broken sign-up process.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried logging in from a brand new OS via fresh browser installation? Seems like it might be a problem with cookies or something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best option would be to simply create a new developer account and sign up for S3 again with a different ID.  This would appear to be a clear Amazon bug and I doubt there's anything that can be done by anyone except Amazon technical support.

Answer (score 0):

When I ran into this it was because I needed to add a new credit card to my account.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue, but this is what AWS is telling me after browsing around on console.aws.amazon.com:

```
Your service sign-up is almost complete!
Thanks for signing up with Amazon Web Services.
```

> Your services may take up to 24 hours to fully activate. If you’re
>   unable to access AWS services after that time, here are a few things
>   you can do to expedite the process:

```
Make sure you provided all necessary information during signup. 
Complete your AWS registration.
Check your email to see if you have received any requests for additional information. 
If you have, please respond to those emails with the information requested.
Verify your credit card information is correct. 
Also, check your credit card activity to see if there’s a $1 authorization (this is not a charge). 
You may need to contact your card issuer to approve the authorization.
If the problem persists, please contact Support:
```

[image]